# Pandas display.max_rows and display.max_colwidth not working in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Pandas and jupyter notebook are not working as intended on my computer. This is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option("max_colwidth", 4, "display.max_rows", 5)
pd.DataFrame({1: ['1' * 1000] * 10000000})
```

But as you can see in the screenshot below, neither of the settings are working
[image: error in pandas]

I want the 1's to be truncated and the rows as well but it isn't working

Comment: `print(pd.get_option("max_colwidth"))
print(pd.get_option("display.max_rows"))`

Comment: Kindly tell me the output of the above code.

Comment: @Mehmaam the result is "4" and "5" which means that it is changing it, but doesn't reflect in jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pandas version that I was on was not the latest.

Broken version: pandas 1.3.0
Working version (latest as of 9/9/22): pandas 1.4.4

Answer (score 0):

Please check the picture I have attached, is it what you want?

[image]

Comment: yes, that's the expected outcome. I am completely lost as to why mine doesn't

Comment: Did you try VSC for your python? how was it now? good?